# Should my Thinkpad X130e be able to charge an Android phone while turned off?

Tags: usb, bios, android, thinkpad, uefi

Having a shortage of power sockets, I wanted to charge my phone and my Thinkpad (X130e) by charging the notebook directly and the phone via USB. In the UEFI settings menu, I have enabled both "Always On USB" and "Always On USB Charge in Off Mode". The former's description claims that with it enabled, the notebook will charge external devices even when turned off. The latter claims the same but specifically for iPads, iPhones and Blackberries.

It doesn't work when I plug in my Android-based smartphone (an Xperia Neo V). Is it supposed to work? If yes, why not, if not, what might be wrong?

Comment: Your phone may simply be trying to draw more power than the board will supply.  I don't have experience with this model so I can't say for sure where that threshold is, but I can say I've seen similar issues in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a toshiba satellite A300 latop which has similar usb options and I have to connect my phone while the machine turned on and then power off the laptop. Doing these steps my phone charges while the laptop is turned off.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the Lenovo ThinkPad W530, and it could not charge any of my mobile phones because none of the USB ports supply enough power.

A reseller told me this is normal behavior with Lenovo laptops - they reduce power available through the USB ports when the laptop is running on battery.